# Select posts that have multiple categories assigned

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I am currently using this code in my WordPress/Timber index.php file to select posts from single categories. I am needing to expand it so posts that have multiple categories checked will be selected and displayed in the loop. The parent category is "stories" and "camping-america,canada,united-states,world" are the children categories. I used this [Timber Wordpress - Show blocks of posts from two categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292113/timber-wordpress-show-blocks-of-posts-from-two-categories) question to implement this code.

**PHP in index.php**

```
$query = array(
'category_name' => 'stories,camping-america,canada,united-states,world',
);
$posts = Timber::get_posts( $query );
$sorted_posts = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // Get first category of post
    $category = $post->category();

    // Fill post back to sorted_posts
    $sorted_posts[ $category->slug ][] = $post;
}

$context['posts'] = $sorted_posts;
```

**Twig code**

```
{% for post in posts.stories %}
   {% include ['tease-stories.twig'] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: @DarkBee The question is selecting posts that have multiple categories assigned to them. Currently the code only selects the parent or first category in the array.